Adding color gradient to a webgl point
Is it possible to give a webgl point not a color but a color gradient?
In webgl I have created a 2D grid consisting of points with a position and a size using this minimal vertex shader:
precision mediump float;
uniform int size;
attribute vec2 position;
attribute vec3 color;
varying vec3 vcolor;
void main() {
    gl_PointSize = float(size);
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, 0.0, 1.0);
    vcolor = color;
}

I can set the color of a point with a fragment shader like this:
precision mediump float;
varying vec3 vcolor;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vcolor, 1.0);
}

But would it be possible to create a gradient across a single point like in this triangle example?

Solution
You need to pass additional information to your shaders, such as the position within the point. This can be done by using the gl_PointCoord built-in variable in the fragment shader, which gives you the coordinates within the point.
Code
Vertex Shader:
precision mediump float;
uniform int size;
attribute vec2 position;
attribute vec3 color;
varying vec3 vcolor;
void main() {
    gl_PointSize = float(size);
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, 0.0, 1.0);
    vcolor = color;
}

Fragment Shader:
precision mediump float;
varying vec3 vcolor;
void main() {
    vec2 coord = gl_PointCoord;
    // Create a gradient based on the coordinates within the point
    vec3 gradientColor = mix(vcolor, vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), coord.x); // Example: gradient from vcolor to red
    gl_FragColor = vec4(gradientColor, 1.0);
}

Notes
In the fragment shader:

gl_PointCoord is a built-in variable that gives you the coordinates within the point, ranging from (0, 0) to (1, 1).

You can use gl_PointCoord to create gradients. In this example, a linear gradient is created along the x-axis of the point from vcolor to red.


